# Elevated PHP Permissions

Tags: php, security, permissions, chmod

We're building an Internet of Things device running Linux. The UI, which configures the device, is built with NGINX + PHP-FPM. Currently, it runs as the "http" user.

We need the ability to run many system level commands (e.g.: configuring NIC / Wi-Fi, changing Hostname, etc.)

How can we safely elevate our privileges to run these commands?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running nginx as a superuser, so research `sudo`.

Comment: go to your server and type sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www. http://askubuntu.com/questions/303593/how-can-i-chmod-777-all-subfolders-of-var-www

Comment: @JosuaMarcelChrisano That won't solve the problem, and it'll introduce some extra security problems.

Comment: We don't have `sudo` on our system.

Comment: I think this is more of a Linux question than PHP. *nix privilege escalation is typically done through [setuid/setgid](http://linuxg.net/how-to-set-the-setuid-and-setgid-bit-for-files-in-linux-and-unix/). Keeping working with a least privilege approach.